# Sending params to the new method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I want to overwrite the default `new` method in a controller to receive some params. What's the best way to do this? Change the route and add an argument to the method like so?

```
get 'article/:id/new', to: 'articles#new', as: :new_article
```

And in the controller:

```
def new(master)
  @article = current_user.articles.new(master)
end
```

Is there a better way to do this? The only way I've got it to work is with a hidden field in the form, too, which isn't at all ideal.

Comment: you don't need to change the route if the route is already a RESTful route (eg `resources :articles`) you just need to add the `new` method/action to the controller and it will all Just Work. However - I am unclear on why you need to pass `master` as an argument to the action? Can you pull that out of params?

Comment: I'm changing how the route works. I want to load a `master` resource to half-fill the form when building `new`.

Comment: that's not how actions work.. they don't take arguments directly. They take parameters via the params hash - so you might as well use the existing new action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a form linking to your `new` action? That's broken right there, it should be just a link.

Just add the params to the link:

```
link_to "New Article", new_article_path( some_param: "some_value" )
```

Then in the controller:

```
def new
  @article = current_user.articles.new some_param: params[:some_param]
end
```

Comment: Two in a row. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I saw your comment and just updated my call to `new` - you were right, I forgot that `params[:some_param]` was just a value, not a hash. You can see now that I added `some_param:` in front so overall a hash is being passed into `new`.

Comment: Totally rad. Got any ideas about storing `:some_param` between `new` and `create`? (As mentioned, don't want to keep my awesome `hidden_field` idea going much longer...)

Comment: In new `session[:some_param] = params[:some_param]`, in create `got_it_back = session[:some_param]`

Comment: Yeah cool, I was thinking `session` would be it. Thanks for all your help man.